# No font lock in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, font-lock

When I the first time enter an `org-mode` buffer, I get no font lock at all unless I `revert-buffer` or reopen the file. Even I turn on the debug mode, no error is emit.

How should I debug and fix this?

Comment: `font-lock-mode` is globally available in all buffers with the default installation of Emacs.  If it is not working in an `org-mode` buffer, then your `init.el` / `.emacs` has something in it that breaks the default behavior.  Try to comment out sections of your user configuration, save, and keep restarting Emacs until you find the portion of code that breaks the font-lock in `org-mode`.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you very much. Following your step, I find that this line `(setq orhc-bibtex-cache-file (expand-file-name ".orhc-bibtex-cache" savefile-directory))` killed the `font-lock`. Strange but I delete the file and everything runs fine.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `org-ref` library, but a quick Google of `orhc-bibtex-cache-file` led me there.  So, your problem may be traceable to that library and it may be helpful to do some debugging to find out which function, etc. might be the culprit.  By preventing the file/variable from being defined, certain functions that rely on testing for the existence of that file cannot do their thing -- i.e., whatever it is that they would do otherwise.